# Can't redirect user to home screen after loggin in

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Basically, I want to create this:

[image: Diagram of the app screens]

It works, the user is redirected on the landing page when not signed in, and when signed in he goes directly to the home page when he starts the app. But when my user is on the sign-in page and clicks on connect, it connects him but it doesn't redirect him to the home page, he stays on the sign-in page and he needs to press return manually two times to end up on the Home screen.
I struggle to close the sign-in page and open the home screen.

Here is the redirection code in main.dart :

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key : key);

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Navigation();
      } else
        return LandingPage();
    });
  }
}
```

The redirection code worked when I was only using the SignIn page (like this)
[image: Diagram]

when the user was logged in It redirected him on the home page but when I added the LandingPage it was broken.

Here is my code : https://github.com/FlorentAero/redirect-issue

Comment: Please include a minimum reproducible example rather than expecting us to read all your code

Comment: Where did you write the navigation logic for that? All I can see is a call to authenticate the user

Comment: Sorry, updated my question.

Comment: "when I added the LandingPage it was broken." How was it broken? When you step through the code in a debugger, which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Stream is the best way to do this. I prefer to check if the user is logged in using initState and in your main.dart you must put that page in your widget "home:"

So it would look like this:

**main.dart**:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      initialRoute: "/",
      home: AuthPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

**AuthPage.dart**:

```
class _AuthPageState extends State<AuthPage> {
  Future<void> _loggedUserValidation() async {
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    FirebaseUser loggedUser = await auth.currentUser();
    if (loggedUser != null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
    } else {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignIn()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loggedUserValidation();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Let me know if it helped.